# Iterate over a hash key/values in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm dabbling with Puppet to update an arbitrary list of appsettings in an ASP.NET web.config (for deployment purpose) and I'm in a dilemma, mostly because I'm a real n00b in puppet.

I have this yaml file (hiera)

```
---
appSettings:
  setting1: "hello"
  setting2: "world!"
  setting3: "lalala"
```

the number of `setting[x]` can span arbitrarily (one appSetting) and I would like to loop through the hash keys/value to update the corresponding `appSetting/add` in the web.config (using `exec` with powershell) the problem is i've searched high and low on how to iterate on *keys* and *values*.

I came across `create_resources` and this of course iterates through a hash of hash with a pre-determined set of keys.  again, the key names are not known within the manifest (hence iterating the key/value pairs).

any guidance is appreciated.

Edit:  looks like there is a `keys()` function i can use over the hash and iterate over that then use hiera_hash('appSettings') to get the hash and iterate through the values.

Comment: The approach sounds somewhat abusive. Wouldn't it be more economic to write the key/value pairs to a file on the agent and have a *single* monolithic PowerShell script do all the editing in one go?

Comment: @FelixFrank sorry i don't quite get why it's "abusive."  the PowerShell script will update the web.config one app setting at a time.  can you elaborate on what a better approach would be?

Comment: ideally you could create a [template](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html) that emits the full contents for your file. Barring that, it would be desirable to manage things in just two resources - one file with the key/value pairs as found in Hiera, and one `exec` with a slightly more powerful script to do the job of all your current execs and apply all the key/value pairs. You'd likely need an additional script to determine if there is work to do on the target file, to form your `onlyif` condition. - Depending on how important performance is, this may be nitpicking

Comment: @FelixFrank oh i see...i originally wanted to use augeas but it's not available in Windows...I came across templating features of puppet but it didn't occur to me that I can use it...thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok i just confirmed that what you can do in your manifest:

```
define updateAppSetting {
    # get the hashes again because outside vars aren't visible here
    $appSettings = hiera_hash('appSettings')

    # $name is the key $appsettingValue is the value
    $appsettingValue = $appSettings[$name]

    # update the web.config here!
}

$appSettings = hiera_hash('appSettings')    

# the keys() function returns the array of hash keys
$appSettingKeys = keys($appSettings)

# iterate through each appSetting key
updateAppSetting{$appSettingKeys:}
```

Comment: `hiera_hash` should not be used **unless** you specifically need Hiera to merge hash values from different hierarchy levels. In almost all normal use cases, you should retrieve your hash data using the regular `hiera` function.

Comment: the merging function of `hiera_hash` is exactly what i need.

Comment: Good question and followup. Don't know why you were down-voted.

Comment: For the given example, I agree that `hiera` (instead of `hiera_hash` would be sufficient. It would return a hash as well without the (in this case unnecessary) merging functionality. But thanks for the code snippet, helped me out with my problem!

Comment: Plus one, i was trying to puzzle this out for days